# Can we say that the ring $R = \frac { \mathbb C[x] }{<x^2+1>}$ is a Principal Ideal ring?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Can we say that the ring $R = \frac{\mathbb C[x] }{<x^2+1>}$ is a Principal Ideal ring?

If we can say that elements except $<x^2+1>$ in every ideal in $ \mathbb C[x]$ which contains $x^2 +1$ is also an ideal in  $R = \frac{\mathbb C[x] }{<x^2+1>}$  then we are able to say.

But can we say the last line.

If it is not true , can anyone please point out  the error ?   I am a first reader of Algebra. Please forgive me if the question is  too easy to be posted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the Chinese remainder theorem, using $x^2+1=(x-i)(x+i)$, we get that
$$
R=\Bbb C[x]/(x^2+1)\\
\cong\Bbb C[x]/(x-i)\times \Bbb C[x]/(x+i)\\
\cong \Bbb C^2
$$
This ring only has four ideals, and each of them is easily checked to be principal.

---

**More details:**

The Chinese remainder theorem. This is a rather large topic all to itself, but here are some details on what happens in this specific case.

Since $x - i + (x^2 + 1)$ is an element of $\Bbb C[x]/(x^2 + 1)$, there is a quotient map
$$
\Bbb C[x]/(x^2 + 1)\to\frac{\Bbb C[x]/(x^2 + 1)}{(x - i + (x^2 + 1)}\cong \Bbb C[x]/(x-i)
$$
Similarily, there is a quotient map
$$
\Bbb C[x]/(x^2 + 1)\to\frac{\Bbb C[x]/(x^2 + 1)}{(x + i + (x^2 + 1)}\cong \Bbb C[x]/(x +i)
$$
The isomorphisms here are given by the third isomorphism theorem: Given a ring $R$ with an ideal $I$, an ideal $J\subseteq R/I$ with corresponding ideal $J'\subseteq R$, then $(R/I)/J\cong R/J'$.

These two homomorphisms together give a homomorphism
$$
\Bbb C[x]/(x^2 + 1) \to \Big(\Bbb C[x]/(x-i), \Bbb C[x]/(x+i)\Big)\cong \Bbb C^2
$$
It turns out that this homomorphism is an isomorphism.

---

The four ideals of $\Bbb C^2$ are 
$$
\{0\}\times \{0\} = ((0,0))\\\Bbb C\times \{0\} = ((1, 0))\\
\{0\}\times \Bbb C = ((0,1))\\
\Bbb C\times \Bbb C = ((1,1))
$$
It's not difficult to show that any generating set generates one of these four ideals.

Comment: Can you say little more on how $R = \frac{\mathbb C[x] }{<x^2+1>} = \frac{\mathbb C[x] }{<x+i>} \times  \frac{\mathbb C[x] }{<x-i>}  $   and how $ \mathbb C^2$ has only four ideals?@Arthur

Comment: @cmi I added some details.

Comment: Thank You. I learnt a lot from your answer.@Arthur

Answer (score 3):

It is true. If $R$ is a PID and $I$ is an ideal in $R$, then the quotient ring $R/I$ is a principal ideal ring  as well.

Indeed, take an ideal $K$ of $R/I$. By the correspondence theorem $K = H/I$ where $H$ is an ideal of $R$ that contains $I$. But $H$ is principal. I.e. $H = (r)$ for some $r \in R$, and it follows that $K = (r)/I = (r+I)$ is principal (here I denote an element of the quotient ring with representant $r$ as $r+I$).

Comment: It's not a domain, though, as $(x^2+1)$ is not a prime ideal. So while it could have only principal ideals, it is not a PID.

Comment: What do you mean? $\mathbb{C}[X]$ is surely a domain.

Comment: Yes, but if you divide out by a non-prime ideal, as in this case, the resulting quotient ring is not a domain.

Comment: Yes, I edited. Thank you.

Comment: every ideal in $ \mathbb C[x]$ which contains $x^2 +1$ is also an ideal in  $R = \frac{\mathbb C[x] }{<x^2+1>}$   ----this is true? @Arthur

Comment: every ideal in $ \mathbb C[x]$ which contains $x^2 +1$ is also an ideal in  $R = \frac{\mathbb C[x] }{<x^2+1>}$   ----is this true?   @Math_QED

Comment: @cmi That doesn't make sense. $\mathbb{C}[X]$ and the quotient you mention are two entirely different sets, so an ideal in the polynomial ring can't be an ideal in the quotient ring.

Comment: @cmi It's almost true. There is a very nice bijective correspondence between the ideals of $\Bbb C[x]$ which contain $(x^2 + 1)$ and the ideals of $\Bbb C[x]/(x^2 + 1)$. They are not the same, but they are closely linked.

Comment: Yea... please overlook the petty notations and check my sense...Though I am editing...@Math_QED

Comment: @Arthur Indeed, that correspondence was even used in my answer!

Comment: why almost true?  Is there anything ?@Arthur

Comment: @cmi "Almost" becaue using the word "is" is too strong. Every ideal in $\Bbb C[x]$ which contains $(x^2 + 1)$ _corresponds to_ an ideal in $\Bbb C[x]/(x^2 + 1)$. It is not _equal to_, so saying that each ideal in one ring _is_ an ideal in the other ring is not right. The correspondence is so strong that you will hear plenty of people use the wrong term about it, though. It's along the same lines as saying that $x$ is an element of $\Bbb C[x]/(x^2 + 1)$, when technically it's $x + (x^2 + 1)$.